# integrating $x^e$

Tags: integration

I know the rule in which the base to power $x$ will always remain the same when integrating or differentiating however I am unsure how to deal with $x^e$. Does the rule also apply to this; otherwise how can I integrate this?

Comment: It reads like $x^c$, where $c\neq -1$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and so the integral is $\frac{x^{e+1}}{e+1}+c$.

Comment: The antiderivative of $x^k$ is (for most cases) $x^{k+1}/(k+1)$ whatever could be $k$ except $-1$.

Comment: so i can just leave it like (x^e+1)/e+1?

Comment: @joe Yes! That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the power rule (i.e. the fact that $\int x^\alpha dx=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+C$) is true for **any** $\alpha \in \Bbb{R \setminus\{-1\}}$, including irrational and transcendental $\alpha$.

So we have that $\int x^edx=\frac{x^{e+1}}{e+1}+C$.